# gremlin server REST restfull Error encountered evaluating script

Tags: rest, gremlin, gremlin-server

I am running a gremlin-server, and using restful api to query it. But I'm confused with this error below :

```
{"message":"Error encountered evaluating script: g.V().next()"}
```

but it is such a simple script.
for other script like "100-1" and "g", the query result is just OK.  I have checked lots times for spelling and character. And I also have checked the gremlin-server logs, but there was no related records. So I ask for your help, Thanks!

Comment: the log from gremlin-server :  WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.handler.HttpGremlinEndpointHandler  - Invalid request - responding with 500 Internal Server Error and Error encountered evaluating script: g.V().next()

Answer (score 0):

You would run into that error if you don't have any data in the graph because it is an unchecked traversal. You should try a query like:

```
if (g.V().hasNext()) { g.V().next() }
```

If you're using Apache TinkerPop 3.1.2 or later, you would have seen a more informative stack trace in the Gremlin Server logs:

> [WARN] HttpGremlinEndpointHandler - Invalid request - responding with 500 Internal Server Error and Error encountered evaluating script: g.V().next()
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.util.FastNoSuchElementException